# Angular Score controller is appending value not incrementing correctly

Tags: angularjs

Could someone please have a look at this controller

The Score is not incrementing the score cookie  by 1 e.g. 1, 2, 3, as required  but just adding 1   so the undesired result is 11 111 1111

```
$scope.score = localStorage.getItem("token");
                $scope.noOfTries = 0;

                $scope.original = $scope.pageTitle;
                $scope.guess = null;
                $scope.deviation = null;

                $scope.verifyGuess = function () {
                    $scope.deviation = $scope.original - $scope.guess;

                    $scope.noOfTries = $scope.noOfTries + 1;
                    $scope.falseAnswer = $scope.deviation != 0;
                    if ($scope.deviation == 0 && $scope.noOfTries == 1){
                        $scope.score = $scope.score += 1;
                        var token = $scope.score;
                        localStorage.setItem("token", //...)
                    };
               }
}
```

Comment: Try this $scope.score = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token"), 10);

Answer (score 2):

This should help;

```
$scope.score = localStorage.getItem("token")) ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token")) : 0;
                $scope.noOfTries = 0;

                $scope.original = $scope.pageTitle;
                $scope.guess = null;
                $scope.deviation = null;

                $scope.verifyGuess = function () {
                    $scope.deviation = $scope.original - $scope.guess;

                    $scope.noOfTries = $scope.noOfTries + 1;
                    $scope.falseAnswer = $scope.deviation != 0;
                    if ($scope.deviation == 0 && $scope.noOfTries == 1){
                        $scope.score = $scope.score += 1;
                        var token = $scope.score;
                        localStorage.setItem("token", token)
                    };
               }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the timely  reply any chance you could put this suggestion in the given code

Comment: @user3265817 i have

Comment: I keep getting a null value for the initial score I've tried to rectify with the following code to no avail 
            $scope.initializeGame = function () {

              if (localStorage.getItem("token").length == 0){

                $scope.score = 0;}

                else {
                  $scope.score = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token"));
                  $scope.noOfTries = 0;

Comment: use this check; `$scope.score = localStorage.getItem("token")) ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token")) : 0;`

Comment: $scope.score = (localStorage.getItem("token")) ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token")) : 0;   worked a charm thankyou

Answer (score 2):

change your `$scope.score = $scope.score += 1;` to :

```
$scope.verifyGuess = function () {
    $scope.deviation = $scope.original - $scope.guess;

    $scope.noOfTries = $scope.noOfTries + 1;
    $scope.falseAnswer = $scope.deviation != 0;
    if ($scope.deviation == 0 && $scope.noOfTries == 1){
        $scope.score = parseInt($scope.score) + 1;
        var token = $scope.score;
        localStorage.setItem("token", //...)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a dive into that how [operators](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp) works in JavaScript.

So in short when you use `'+'` operator with Sting it do concatenation and when you do `'+'` operator with numbers it perform addition.

In your case `'$scope.score'` seems to be string. So it's performing concatenation. Make it number and it will work as add operator. use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for conversion.

$scope.score = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token"),10);

So your code will look like

```
$scope.score = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("token"),10);
                $scope.noOfTries = 0;

                $scope.original = $scope.pageTitle;
                $scope.guess = null;
                $scope.deviation = null;

                $scope.verifyGuess = function () {
                    $scope.deviation = $scope.original - $scope.guess;

                    $scope.noOfTries = $scope.noOfTries + 1;
                    $scope.falseAnswer = $scope.deviation != 0;
                    if ($scope.deviation == 0 && $scope.noOfTries == 1){
                        $scope.score = $scope.score + 1;
                        var token = $scope.score;
                        localStorage.setItem("token", //...)
                    };
               }
}
```

**EDIT**

**Why Radix is recommended to pass**

> If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the
>   following:
>
> - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16    (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10    (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is
>     implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal)
>     is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason
>     always specify a radix when using parseInt.
> - If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10    (decimal)

For more details please follow [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
.

Comment: Why do you add the `radix` parameter of `10` in the `parseInt` function?

Comment: @daan.desmedt because if radix is undefined or 0 then javascript make assumptions based on the string passed. So it is recommended to pass the radix. You can find the more details on this in the link inside the answer.